# Vary basic question about the native pipe and tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't figure out what works and what doesn't with the native pipe. Here are 2 examples, that I expect to work, but fail. I guess my problem is that I though it would work like the magrittr pipe.

Is there some variation of option 1 or 2 that achieves the same result as 3?

```
library(tidyverse)

# 1. What I think will  work, but does not work:
mtcars |> 
  n_distinct(gear)

# 2. What I think will  work, but does not work:
mtcars |> 
  n_distinct(_$gear)

# 3. Does work
mtcars |> 
  pull(gear) |> 
  n_distinct()
```

EDIT:
The answer is that it most likely depends on whether the function expects a vector or a data frame.

Both answers do a good job of answering this question, but @r2evans answer is probably more helpful for others, so I will mark that as the solution.

Comment: Well, your first example does not work with `%>%` either. For more on the differences see e.g. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/04/base-vs-magrittr-pipe/ or [What are the differences between R's native pipe `|>` and the magrittr pipe `%>%`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe)

Comment: Thanks @stefan. It looks like pull() is recommended there. Still, in some cases, it is possible to have a data frame on the left-hand side and then select a column without using pull. I guess that is what I'm asking. For example `mtcars |> filter(gear == 3)` works. Any clue as to what the difference is? I guess it depends on the function used on the right-hand-side?

Comment: `magrittr` has a pipe for that matter, called the exposition pipe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008076/should-i-use-instead-of

Comment: While @Maël's suggestion to use `%$%` works, it is not normally re-exported by `dplyr` or `tidyverse`, so you'd need an additional `library(magrittr)` to get at that operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the function must be intended to operate on a `data.frame` (or frame-like, such as `tbl_df`), not on a vector. `mutate`/`summarize` and such all work on frames, whereas some of `dplyr`'s functions are meant to operate on vectors, whether inside a call to `mutate` (...) or not. These non-frame functions must be given a vector.

TLDR: `with` is a cheater function that supports the non-standard evaluation you're looking for: `mtcars |> with(n_distinct(gear))` works (among many other expressions).

You can distinguish between what verbs can work like you have tried here (unwrapped, so to speak) by checking their args: if the first argument is something like `.data=` or `data=` or `x=` (all expecting a `data.frame`-like object), then it can be used immediately after `|>` or `%>%`. For instance, `mutate`, `summarize`, and `reframe` all have something like this in their help pages:

```
Arguments:

   .data: A data frame, data frame extension (e.g. a tibble), or a lazy
          data frame (e.g. from dbplyr or dtplyr). See _Methods_,
          below, for more details.
```

Even `tidyr` functions (that work on the top-level like that) are similar, with

```
Usage:

     pivot_wider(
       data,
       ...,
       id_cols = NULL,
       <truncated>
```

Whereas with `n_distinct`, all of its arguments:

```
Usage:

     n_distinct(..., na.rm = FALSE)
     
Arguments:

     ...: Unnamed vectors. If multiple vectors are supplied, then they
          should have the same length.
```

where its first (and optionally more) argument is a *vector*.

I infer the intended use of `n_distinct` to return an integer, so we can easily adapt your first attempt to get what we need:

```r
n_distinct(mtcars$gear)
# [1] 3
mtcars |> with(n_distinct(gear))
# [1] 3
mtcars |>
  summarize(ngears = n_distinct(gear)) |>
  pull(ngears)
# [1] 3
```

You asked about `dplyr`-specific verbs and the pipe, but the notion that the counting function (`n_distinct`) does not operate on its own is the same with a very similar package `data.table`, where its verbs need to operate either on a vector or within its `[`-scope (which is analogous in effect to needing to be within `dplyr`'s verbs):

```r
data.table::uniqueN(mtcars$gear)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, uniqueN(gear)]
# blend of dplyr/data.table
as.data.table(mtcars)[, n_distinct(gear)]
```

The biggest reason this is the case is because `dplyr` and `data.table` both allow for non-standard evaluation (NSE) of column names. This is supported in a few base R functions (`with`, `withint`, `subset`, and `transform` come to mind, there are others), but it is prevalent in `dplyr` and `data.table`. This (NSE) is how you are able to do something like

```r
mtcars |>
  summarize(ngears = n_distinct(gear))
```

and not have to reference `mtcars$gear` instead of `gear`. (For a few reasons, `mtcars$gear` inside of `mutate`/`summarize`/... is actively discouraged in `dplyr` anyway).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned `n_distinct` does not accept a data frame or tibble, it accepts a vector. This works without `pull` :

```
mtcars |> _$gear |> n_distinct()
## [1] 3
```

so does this:

```
mtcars$gear |> n_distinct()
```

Comment: The use of `mtcars |> _$gear` is listed as an "experimental feature" in the 4.3.0 release notes. This was not possible in earlier versions.

Comment: It seems clear from the question that the poster wants to use that.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you need a newer version of R for this to work. I tested in my local R and got the error "Error: pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument" because I was running an older version.

Comment: I sometimes need to use an older version of R that even predates |> and in that case I use %>% instead.  Replace |> with %>% and _ with dot :  `mtcars %>% .$gear %>%  n_distinct()`

Comment: Thank you for the addition. This was what I was looking for in the first place.